# how can i get img paths using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
           <div class="em-main" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="em-div-head" align="center"> E-Shop Jewellery </div>
           <div class="em-textbox" style="border:hidden">
              <input type="text" value="To:" name="recipient" style="width:97%">
           </div>
        <div id="em">
             <div class="em-middle">
              <div style="border-bottom:solid 1px #CCCCCC">
              <textarea class="em-textarea" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Write a 
                message..'; }" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Write a message..') { this.value = 
                  ''; }" value="Write a message.." name="message">Write a message..</textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="em_rt_tp_scroller" class="em_rt_tp_scroller">
            <div id="em-rightscrollerimage" style="border:none">
     <div class="em-mdimage"><img class="mail" src=" http://localhost:8080/weather
       /servlets.ImgDisplayServlet?id=D:\EML\workspace\assets\tried-
         imgs\18__1882_IMG_5731_203_173.png " alt="imagecontainer image" style="max-
           height:100%; max-width:100%;">
         <ul>
        <img id="em-delete" class="removeicon" width="7" height="7" title="Remove" bottom="10%" 
          src="jqe13/image/delete_s.PNG">
          </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="em-mdimage">
           <img class="mail" src=" http://localhost:8080/weather
              /servlets.ImgDisplayServlet?id=D:\EML\workspace\assets\tried-
              imgs\13__1882_IMG_5731_120_124.png " alt="imagecontainer image" style="max-
                height:100%; max-width:100%;">
             <ul>
             <img id="em-delete" class="removeicon" width="7" height="7" title="Remove"        
                  bottom="10%" src="jqe13/image/delete_s.PNG">
             </ul> 
         </div>
         <div class="em-mdimage">
          <img class="mail" src=" http://localhost:8080/weather
             /servlets.ImgDisplayServlet?id=D:\EML\workspace\assets\tried-
              imgs\15__1882_IMG_5731_341_137.png " alt="imagecontainer image" style="max-
               height:100%; max-width:100%;">
             <ul>
              <img id="em-delete" class="removeicon" width="7" height="7" title="Remove"    
                bottom="10%" src="jqe13/image/delete_s.PNG">
             </ul>
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
         <div class="em-bottom" align="center">
             <input id="SEND" type="button" value="send" name="">
              <input id="CANCEL" type="button" value="cancel" name="">
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

the above code is running html code for mailing including image sources.i am attaching 3 images 
     to the  class="em-mdimage".can any one help me for getting all 3 images path(like D:\EML
    \workspace\assets\tried-imgs\18__1882_IMG_5731_203_173.png ) using jquery .then i will send 
     those 3 paths to my servlet when click on "send" button.
  I am new to jquery.I tried some selectors but i didn't get those paths.
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry if I have misread the question, I am on a phone but would the function .attr('src') help?

Comment: jQuery's .attr('src') should help you out. You may need to pop it in an array but that will get you the info you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** get the system file path (e.g., `D:\EML\workspace\assets\tried-imgs\18__1882_IMG_5731_203_173.png`)

**The browser does not have access to your local file system** and it goes without saying that JavaScript does not have access to the remote file system, too.

You can just get the image `src` attributes

```
$("img").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: $('#SEND').live('click', function(event){
 var s;
    var imgs="";
     $(".mail").each(function(){
  var i= $(this).attr("src");
   console.log(i);
   var path = i.split("=");
   imgs = imgs + path[1] + '~';
   console.log(imgs);
 });
   s = imgs;
    console.log(s);});

Comment: according to my requirement i change ur code into above lines then i got output like this........undefined~D:\EML\workspace\assets\tried-imgs\18__1688_IMG_5749_140_10‌​1.png ~D:\EML\workspace\assets\tried-imgs\1__1688_IMG_5749_134_117.png ~D:\EML\workspace\assets\tried-imgs\15__1688_IMG_5749_144_123.png ~ but i got "undefined" before path due to this line " imgs = imgs + path[1] + '~';" .....if its not get i will send perfect paths to my servlet...please give me any suggestions...thank you in advance ... :)

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you,
alert( $('img')[0].src );